# I would like to use IMacros to delete facebook posts on a group page without navigating to the page I made the macro on

Tags: facebook, imacros, facebook-group

I would like to use IMacros to delete facebook posts on a group page by starting with a search for my posts by name then skipping the first and deleting all others. I can make this macro but When I play it it always wants to navigate to the page I made the macro on.  How can I get it to just run the macro on the page I have already navigated too?  I want to run it on one page at a time and I will go to the next page manually.

Answer (score 0):

iMacros by DEFAULT records the url of the page. Remove the

```
URL GOTO=www.link.com
```

from the #Current.iim

The u can use PAUSE command to pause the iMacros macro execution when you feel like to.